# What's the difference between the balance point and the median?

Tags: statistics

I would like to know what the difference is between the median and the balancing point of a dataset. A lot of sources that I am reading from say that the balance point is essentially the mean, but from what I can tell, it's more similar to the median.

Comment: It will help (us and you) if you add a definition of balancing point to the question.  I could "guess" what it means (from a physics perspective) but that might not be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a set of data $\{1,4,10000\}$. In this case the median is $4$. Now imagine we have a ruler with markings from $1,4,\cdots ,10000$, and we place a weight on the points $1,4,10000$. If we put a pivot at the point $4$, such that it becomes the "balance point", then the ruler would certainly tip over because the two sides are obviously unbalanced (not going to go into the physics here). On the other hand if we put the pivot at the point $3335$, the mean of the dataset, the ruler would not tip over. This is why the mean is sometimes called the "balance point" in some elementary textbooks.

Comment: I'm confused, why is the median of that set 2? Isn't it supposed to be 4?
I do now understand what is the balance point is now though, so thank you!

Comment: @AshTheBird ahh that was a typo. Fixed it now

Comment: I have another question; Why would the balance point be 3335, and not 50000?

Comment: @AshTheBird why 50000?

Comment: sorry, meant 5000. I'm saying this because if it was 3335, the ruler would still tilt over to a right.

Comment: @AshTheBird why would it tilt? you can try calculating the moments if you know how to do it. Again I'm not gonna go into the physics behind this

Comment: There are 10000 marks on the ruler that have weight on each one. If we put the pivot at 3335, there is still weight on the right side.

Comment: @AshTheBird i didn't mention the marks have weights

Comment: Oh! Now I get it (I think). If we put the pivot at the point 3335, the weights that 1 and 4 have will balance out the right side. Sorry for misunderstanding!